# Firebase and facebook login

Tags: angularjs, facebook, firebase

So here is my issue,
I am working on a service using firebase. 
You login with your email and password.
You then can connect a page account by email user.
You do so by logging in through facebook, getting the page accounts through the fb.api and associating the page to the email.

My issue is as follow:
- In order to sign in, you need to disconnect from your personal one, then connect, disconnect and login again.

Is there anyway I can do all the operations I need to do without having to disconnect them from their account, using some type of sandbox or something?

Cheers,
Haytham